# Java Import into JTable from JSON File

Tags: java, json

I am stuck and cant really find a way to get the components out of the JSON String into variables.
Have tried many things but yet to come up with an answer.I would be thankful if someone help me unstuck by correcting possible mistakes or even enlighten me up with an answer so i can continue with my project.

Using json-simple-1.1.

The JTable is exported to a json using this:

```
String filePath = "D:\\Java\\WorkSchedule\\saveWorkers.json";
                File file = new File(filePath);
                try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filePath)){  
                boolean firstRow=true;
                  fw.write("[");
                    for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
                        for (int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                            Object value = table.getValueAt(i, j);
                            String columnName = table.getColumnName(j);
                            System.out.println(columnName + " : " + value );
                            jsonObj.put(columnName,value);
                        }
                        fw.write(firstRow ? jsonObj.toString() : ("," + jsonObj.toString()));
                        firstRow = false;
                    }
                    fw.write("]");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }       
            }
```

It creates the following JSON :

[{"Firstname":"George ","WorkHours":"15","Lastname":"Hamachi","WorkID":"1"},{"Firstname":"Bill","WorkHours":"20","Lastname":"Gates","WorkID":"2"},{"Firstname":"John","WorkHours":"35","Lastname":"Wills","WorkID":"3"}]

This is the import method i use atm:

```
String filePath = "D:\\Java\\WorkSchedule\\saveWorkers.json";
                File file = new File(filePath);
                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                String fname = null;
                try {
                    Object obj =  parser.parse(new FileReader(filePath));   
                    JSONArray Array = (JSONArray) obj;
                    System.out.println(Array);

                } catch ( IOException | org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a suggestion, Use `Gson`. It handles these cases pretty well. You can easily get each node as an entity and access their variables.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws ParseException
{
    String json = "[{\"Firstname\":\"George \",\"WorkHours\":\"15\",\"Lastname\":\"Hamachi\",\"WorkID\":\"1\"},{\"Firstname\":\"Bill\",\"WorkHours\":\"20\",\"Lastname\":\"Gates\",\"WorkID\":\"2\"},{\"Firstname\":\"John\",\"WorkHours\":\"35\",\"Lastname\":\"Wills\",\"WorkID\":\"3\"}]";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Person[] person = gson.fromJson( json, Person[].class );
}

public static class Person
{
    @SerializedName("Firstname")
    private String firstName;
    @SerializedName("WorkHours")
    private int workHours;
    @SerializedName("Lastname")
    private String lastName;
    @SerializedName("WorkID")
    private int workID;

    // Getters and Setters go here
}
```

If you really want to use `JSON.simple` then, this would be one approach

```
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray parsedArr = ( JSONArray ) jsonParser.parse( json );

    for( Object object : parsedArr )
    {
        JSONObject myObj = ( JSONObject ) object;
        String firstName = ( String ) myObj.get( "Firstname" );
        int workHours = Integer.parseInt( ( String ) myObj.get( "WorkHours" ) );
        String lastName = ( String ) myObj.get( "Lastname" );
        int workID = Integer.parseInt( ( String ) myObj.get( "WorkID" ) );

        System.out.println( firstName + " " + lastName + " " + workHours + " " + workID );
    }
```